# JWT Auth Invalid Token

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am using jwt auth for the token work in laravel. Its working fine on rest client but when I call it in web service, out of 10 times, 2 times it returns invalid_token error. When ever internet speed is fast, it starts returning invalid_token, on 2G, it is working fine. Can any one please let me know the solution?

Is their some timing issue?

Comment: which package do you use to generate tokens? Check your `ttl` as well

Comment: @CerlinBoss ttl is 60 min